# Minimizer of a function containing response and predicting variables

Tags: predictor, function

Can anyone please give me the expression of the "minimizer" of $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \vert y_i - b x_i \vert + \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - b x_i)^2 \quad \quad ?$$

I am unable to find this expression on the internet. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Here, $y_i$'s are response variables and $x_i$'s are predictor variables.

Comment: Is there anything that makes you confident that the minimizer will have an explicit closed form?